# Correlation in R - missing values

Tags: r, correlation

I want to run correlations on the following dataset. I want correlations among all (V1 with V2, V3, V4, V5; V2 with V1, V3, V4, V5 and so on...). I want the correlation coefficient and the p-values.

mydataset

```
   Group    V1        V2          V3         V4       V5
   OH      0.3        5          -3.09      2.5      NA
   OH      0.5        1           NA        1.8      2.5 
   ON      2          2.5         NA       -3.11    -7.5
   OH      1.5       -3.35       -0.82       NA     -2.5
   ON      6.5       -2.85        2.5        NA      NA
   OH      3          0.5         1.8      -2.85     NA
```

I ran this code

```
    correlations <- corr.test (mydataset, use = "pairwise").
```

I have also run:

```
    correlations <- cor(mydataset, use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
```

I don't know how to deal with missing values. And I am not getting any output whatsoever. I keep getting this error:

```
    Error in cor(x, use = use, method = method) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Any suggestions on what might work?

Thanks!

Comment: It's trying to use the `Group` column as well, since that's what you provided it. (I'm assuming the rest of your columns are actually numeric; you might check that too.)

Comment: Keep only numeric columns in your dataset and do `corr.test (mydataset, use = "pairwise")`. The command will exclude NAs automatically. You can check that on the sample table it will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the NA's, but rather that variable `Group` is not numeric. So try

```
 cor(mydataset[sapply(mydataset, is.numeric)], use='pairwise')
```

This will only select numeric variables and exclude NA.

```
        V1         V2         V3         V4         V5
V1  1.0000000 -0.5917056  0.8907941 -0.9355822 -0.9819805
V2 -0.5917056  1.0000000 -0.6376181  0.4894776 -0.2468321
V3  0.8907941 -0.6376181  1.0000000 -1.0000000         NA
V4 -0.9355822  0.4894776 -1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
V5 -0.9819805 -0.2468321         NA  1.0000000  1.0000000
```

In the correlation matrix we see that we get NA for correlation between `V3` and `V5`, but that is because `V3` and `V5` are not simultaneously NA only in one observation, and you can't get correlation only on one pair of points.

Comment: V1                 _V2 
V1                      .0000000    0.5659588                                                                               V2                      0.533333    0.65368                                                                                    Thanks! I had already tried that and i get something like above. It gives the output for variables having no NA at all, but R is not picking up my other columns at all! Any suggestions??

Comment: I get a full correlation matrix. The only NA result I get is for V3,V5, but that is because given the data you provided, V3 and V5 are both simultaneously not NA only in 3rd observation. And you can't have correlation with only one pair.

Answer (score 0):

`corr.test(test[2:6], use = 'pairwise')` is what you want. You have to exclude the first column, which is a character vector. Below is a reprex with output. You get the coefficients and p-values.

```r
library('tidyverse')
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
#> ✔ tibble  1.3.4     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
#> ✔ tidyr   0.7.2     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
#> ✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.2.0
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
library('psych')
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'psych'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     %+%, alpha
test = tibble::tribble(
  ~Group, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3, ~V4, ~V5,
  'OH',      0.3,        5,          -3.09,      2.5,      NA,
  'OH',      0.5,        1,           NA,        1.8,      2.5,
  'ON',      2 ,         2.5,         NA,       -3.11,    -7.5,
  'OH',      1.5,       -3.35,       -0.82,       NA,     -2.5,
  'ON',      6.5,       -2.85,        2.5,        NA,      NA,
  'OH',      3,          0.5,         1.8,      -2.85,     NA
)
corr.test(test[2:6], use = 'pairwise')
#> Warning in sqrt(n - 2): NaNs produced
#> Warning in corr.test(test[2:6], use = "pairwise"): Number of subjects must
#> be greater than 3 to find confidence intervals.
#> Warning in sqrt(n[lower.tri(n)] - 3): NaNs produced
#> Call:corr.test(x = test[2:6], use = "pairwise")
#> Correlation matrix 
#>       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#> V1  1.00 -0.59  0.89 -0.94 -0.98
#> V2 -0.59  1.00 -0.64  0.49 -0.25
#> V3  0.89 -0.64  1.00 -1.00    NA
#> V4 -0.94  0.49 -1.00  1.00  1.00
#> V5 -0.98 -0.25    NA  1.00  1.00
#> Sample Size 
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> V1  6  6  4  4  3
#> V2  6  6  4  4  3
#> V3  4  4  4  2  1
#> V4  4  4  2  4  2
#> V5  3  3  1  2  3
#> Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
#>      V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
#> V1 0.00 0.86 0.66 0.45 0.66
#> V2 0.22 0.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
#> V3 0.11 0.36 0.00  NaN   NA
#> V4 0.06 0.51  NaN 0.00  NaN
#> V5 0.12 0.84   NA  NaN 0.00
#> 
#>  To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```